# How can I clone a git repository to another machine?

Tags: git, ssh, git-clone

Let's say I have a git repository on machine A (local). I would like to clone it to machine B (far away), as if I ssh-ed onto B and ran `git clone me@A:/repo.git`, but I can only ssh from A to B, and not from B to A. So how can I clone the repo from A to B?

Answer (score 0):

on the remote.

```
git init $DIR/$PROJECT
```

on the local

```
git remote add $remote user@machine:$DIR/$PROJECT
git fetch $remote
git push $remote branch
```

should do it fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have several ways (protocols) depend on your installation.
you can either follow the previous answer and add remote+fetch form it or you can direct clone using one of the following protocols - ssh/http/git.

There is another question that you need to ask yourself - do you need read only or read&write credentials to the cloned repository.

More about the different protocols and more info: (including how to clone)

http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html